# Using 'ד for Hashem's Name

Tags: shemos-sacred-names, tallit-gadol

Many tallitot have the bracha before putting on the tallit written on the atarah. But as you can see in the picture below, the Name of Hashem is abbreviated as a 'ד when it is usually rendered 'ה. The point of the abbreviation is so that the tallit can be discarded without a problem of disposing a Divine Name.

[image]

Since 'ה is already an abbreviation to avoid using the Tetragrammaton, why do they use a 'ד when 'ה already has no holiness associated with it?

Comment: Dalet = 4 = 4 letters in yud-key-vav-key? Or because it is the letter before Hey so the "closest" replacement?

Comment: @mbloch The hey already has no kedushah, so why use a daled?

Comment: @mbloch, so why isn't dalet used everywhere rather than heh?  Why two abbreviations?  Is dalet used anywhere else?  There must be something unique to a tallit...

Comment: @ezra the same reason that people don't write God G-d even if God has no kedusha on its own, especially when written on a computer screen (since "electronic words are not words") ? speculating otherwise I'd post it as an answer

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi no many people abbreviate yud-kay-vav-kay on paper as Dalet - which is why I am speculating it is because dalet represents the "four letter name of God"

Comment: I've seen it more in Sefard (non-Mizrachi) books, and therefore I suppose it might have connection with the word "deo" in Latin and its counterparts in Romance languages. Extra feature that ה itself has some sanctity,  thus one can avoid its desecration by using ד.

Comment: I don't claim to have seen daled used that often. But I know that I have seen it in places other than a tallit. I assume that it is the daled from "Adonai". I can't say why one might be used over another. Probably just preference.

Comment: Pretty sure we have this question already, but I can't find it.

Comment: @DanF This is written in JE (last sentence). But in this case why not א'? http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/4853-dalet

Comment: are you sure it is a dalet and not a hey without the leg (or that it could have been at some point before evolving into a proper dalet)?

Comment: Interestingly, Wikipedia also mentions that Daled is used on tallitot. No good explanation of why.

Comment: @Kazibácsi What an extreme failure on that Jewish Encyclopedia page! Everywhere where there should be a ד they have a ר!

Comment: @ezra I didn't want to comment on that, since others were really strict regarding off-topic issues! :-D

Comment: "If you make the dalet into a resh, you will destroy the world." [Shir HaShirim Rabbah 5:11] [Because "echad" becomes "achar".]

Comment: @Maurice Mizrahi Where is the atarah from? In Ladino  dio is used instead of Spanish dios, which strangely is pluralized. Also dio in Italian. Or is your question as to why dalet is used -- because that makes the word closer to the name which shouldn't be destroyed if its written?

Comment: This isn’t unique to talleisim - I see people use this abbreviation all the time.

Answer (score 1):

I asked a rosh yeshiva. His answer was that a tallit was special in that people sometimes enter toilets with it (by mistake). As such, for *zehirut* (carefulness), one uses the letter Dalet so as not to enter with something that has even a letter from God's name.

Beyond this, to recap from comments above (which might get deleted at some point), MY users have suggested a few other possibilities

- Dalet = 4 = 4 letters in yud-key-vav-key ([mbloch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11501/mbloch))
- A connection with the word "deus" (god) in Latin and its [counterparts](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deus#Descendants) in Romance languages. Extra feature that ה itself has some sanctity, thus one can avoid its desecration by using ד ([Kazi bácsi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/15256/kazi-b%C3%A1csi))
- the Daled from "Adonai" ([DanF](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/5275/danf))
- a Hey without the leg ([rosends](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1362/rosends))

Comment: The problem here is that if you accept that heh' has even a shred of holiness in it, then you can't do anything you want with something that has a heh' on it -- which defeats the purpose of using just heh' for God's name.

Comment: Well maybe that is exactly the point of using Dalet. With Dalet you can do anything you want

Comment: Its a little like Ladino's Dio, not dios as in spanish which  for some strange reason is pluralized.

Comment: If we're worried about an abbreviated Hay, wouldn't the "Elokainu" afterwords be more problematic?

Comment: @salmon especially because אל is already a full name of God on its own

Answer (score 0):

Does [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalet#Significance) count as a source?

> A reason for this is that the He is used as an abbreviation for HaShem "The Name" and the dalet is used as a non-sacred way of referring to God.

Note, though, that they have a “citation needed” slapped on that sentence.